# Get mouse coordinates in QChartView's axis system

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

Is there a way to get mouse's coordinates on plotting area of a `QChartView`? Preferably in the axis units. The goal is to display mouse's coordinates while moving the mouse around on the plot so the user can measure plotted objects.

I couldn't find any built in function for this on `QChartView`, so I'm trying to use `QChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` to try and calculate the resulting position in the plotting area. The problem is I can't get any reference to the plot area's coordinate system.
I've tried using `mapToScene`, `mapToItem` and `mapToParent` and also the reverse `mapFrom...` on all objects I can grab a hold of to try to do this, but to no avail.

I've found that `QChartView::chart->childItems()[2]` is indeed the plotting area, excluding the axis and axis labels. I can then call `QChartView::chart->childItems()[2]->setCursor(Qt::CrossCursor)` to make a cross appear only on the plotting area and not on the adjacent objects. But still, nothing I try seems to make a correct reference to this object's coordinate system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`QChartView` is simply a `QGraphicsView` with an embedded `scene()`. To get coordinates within any of the charts, you have to go through several coordinate transformations:

1. Start with the view widget coordinates
2. `view->mapToScene`: widget (view) coordinates → scene coordinates
3. `chart->mapFromScene`: scene coordinates → chart item coordinates
4. `chart->mapToValue`: chart item coordinates → value in a given series.
5. End with value coordinates in a given series.

The term "chart item" and "chart widget" are synonyms, since `QChart` is-a `QGraphicsWidget` is-a `QGraphicsItem`. Note that `QGraphicsWidget` is **not** a `QWidget`!

Implementing it like this works like a charm (thanks, Marcel!):

```
auto const widgetPos = event->localPos();
auto const scenePos = mapToScene(QPoint(static_cast<int>(widgetPos.x()), static_cast<int>(widgetPos.y()))); 
auto const chartItemPos = chart()->mapFromScene(scenePos); 
auto const valueGivenSeries = chart()->mapToValue(chartItemPos); 
qDebug() << "widgetPos:" << widgetPos; 
qDebug() << "scenePos:" << scenePos; 
qDebug() << "chartItemPos:" << chartItemPos; 
qDebug() << "valSeries:" << valueGivenSeries;
```

Comment: That seems to be the correct combination of coordinate mapping. What I ended up doing was subclassing QChartView and implementing `chart()->mapToValue()` within `QChartView::mouseMoveEvent()`, which worked right away. The subclassing was useful for implementing Zooming and Panning too.