# Implement selection on QChartView

Tags: qt, plot, qt5, qtcharts, qchart

I want to make an implementation of chart selection based on [QChart](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qchart.html) and [QChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qchartview.html).
The family of the classes have a big advantage - [easy use of openGL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qabstractseries.html#useOpenGL-prop) and [animations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qchart.html#animationOptions-prop), for example:

```
QLineSeries *series = new QLineSeries();
series->setUseOpenGL(true); // <==

QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations); // <==

QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

The [QChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qchartview.html#details) class provides the useful zoom feature - [QChartView::setRubberBand()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qchartview.html#setRubberBand):

```
chartView->setRubberBand(QChartView::RectangleRubberBand);
```

[image]

The main problem is that the rubber band can be used only for zoom, but I need to implement it for horizontal selection without zoom, as the feature usually implemented in audio editors:
[image]

Now, when I have inherit QChartView, I can disable zoom after selection:

```
class ChartView : public QChartView
...
bool m_drawRubberBand;
QRubberBand m_rubberBand;
...

ChartView::ChartView(QChart *chart, QWidget *parent) 
    : QChartView(chart, parent)
{
    setRubberBand(QChartView::HorizontalRubberBand);
}
...

// Just copy-paste from the Qt 5 sources - file \Src\qtcharts\src\charts\qchartview.cpp:
/*!
If the rubber band rectangle is displayed in the press event specified by
\a event, the event data is used to update the rubber band geometry.
Otherwise, the default QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent() implementation is called.
*/
void ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (m_drawRubberBand && m_rubberBand.isVisible()) 
    {
        QRect rect = chart()->plotArea().toRect();
        int width = event->pos().x() - m_rubberBandOrigin.x();
        int height = event->pos().y() - m_rubberBandOrigin.y();
        if (!rubberBand().testFlag(VerticalRubberBand)) 
        {
            m_rubberBandOrigin.setY(rect.top());
            height = rect.height();
        }
        if (!rubberBand().testFlag(HorizontalRubberBand))
        {
            m_rubberBandOrigin.setX(rect.left());
            width = rect.width();
        }
        m_rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(m_rubberBandOrigin.x(), m_rubberBandOrigin.y(), width, height).normalized());
    }
    else 
    {
        QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Then I can just don't implement the zoom action on the mouse key release event:

```
void ChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (m_rubberBand.isVisible()) 
    {
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            m_drawRubberBand = false;    
            do_nothing(); // <==
        }

    }
}
```

So, my questions now:

1. How borders of the the visual rubber band can be mapped to real chart's coordinates. I.e., how can the selection be mapped into a line series on the chart? Now I receive same wrong coordinates:

   ```
     void MyView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) 
     {
         QChartView::resizeEvent(event);

         QRect rct(QPoint(10, 10), QPoint(20, 20));
         qDebug() << mapToScene(rct); <==
     }
   ```

Output:

```
QPolygonF(QPointF(10,10)QPointF(21,10)QPointF(21,21)QPointF(10,21))
QPolygonF(QPointF(10,10)QPointF(21,10)QPointF(21,21)QPointF(10,21))
QPolygonF(QPointF(10,10)QPointF(21,10)QPointF(21,21)QPointF(10,21))
QPolygonF(QPointF(10,10)QPointF(21,10)QPointF(21,21)QPointF(10,21))
...
```

2. How can an existing rubber selection be proportionally resized together with the view?

**Edit:** May be it is a useful keyword - [QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#setSelectionArea).

[The Qt 5 chip example which provides nice rubber band selection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html), but the example based on [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html), not on QChartView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is resolved thanks to the reply to this answer: [Get mouse coordinates in QChartView's axis system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44067831/4149835)

The key moment: it was necessary to invoke [QChart::mapToValue()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qchart.html#mapToValue) for a correct coordinates transform:

```
QPointF ChartView::point_to_chart(const QPoint &pnt)
{
    QPointF scene_point = mapToScene(pnt);
    QPointF chart_point = chart()->mapToValue(scene_point);

    return chart_point;
}
```

And the inverse transformation:

```
QPoint ChartView::chart_to_view_point(QPointF char_coord)
{
    QPointF scene_point = chart()->mapToPosition(char_coord);
    QPoint view_point = mapFromScene(scene_point);

    return view_point;
}
```

That's how I have implemented resize of the rubber band on the [resizeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent).
   **Firstly**, I save the current rubber band on mouse release event:

```
void ChartView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (m_rubberBand.isVisible()) 
    {
        update_rubber_band(event);            
        m_drawRubberBand = false;
        save_current_rubber_band(); <==            
    }
}
```

Where:

```
void ChartView::update_rubber_band(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    QRect rect = chart()->plotArea().toRect();
    int width = event->pos().x() - m_rubberBandOrigin.x();
    int height = event->pos().y() - m_rubberBandOrigin.y();
    if (!rubberBand().testFlag(VerticalRubberBand))
    {
        m_rubberBandOrigin.setY(rect.top());
        height = rect.height();
    }
    if (!rubberBand().testFlag(HorizontalRubberBand))
    {
        m_rubberBandOrigin.setX(rect.left());
        width = rect.width();
    }
    m_rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(m_rubberBandOrigin.x(), m_rubberBandOrigin.y(), width, height).normalized());
}
```

And:

```
void ChartView::save_current_rubber_band()
{
    QRect rect = m_rubberBand.geometry();

    QPointF chart_top_left = point_to_chart(rect.topLeft());
    m_chartRectF.setTopLeft(chart_top_left);

    QPointF chart_bottom_right = point_to_chart(rect.bottomRight());
    m_chartRectF.setBottomRight(chart_bottom_right);
}
```

**And how I repaint the rubber on the resize event:**

```
void ChartView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QChartView::resizeEvent(event);

    if (m_rubberBand.isVisible())
    {
        restore_rubber_band();
    }

    apply_nice_numbers();
}
```

Where:

```
void ChartView::restore_rubber_band()
{
    QPoint view_top_left = chart_to_view_point(m_chartRectF.topLeft());
    QPoint view_bottom_right = chart_to_view_point(m_chartRectF.bottomRight());

    m_rubberBandOrigin = view_top_left;
    m_rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(view_top_left, view_bottom_right));
}
```

And don't forget about the ["nice numbers"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qvalueaxis.html#applyNiceNumbers):

```
void ChartView::apply_nice_numbers()
{
    QList<QAbstractAxis*> axes_list = chart()->axes();
    for each(QAbstractAxis* abstract_axis in axes_list)
    {
        QValueAxis* value_axis = qobject_cast<QValueAxis*>(abstract_axis);
        if (value_axis)
        {
            value_axis->applyNiceNumbers();
        }
    }
}
```

This logic in action.
Before resize:
[image]

After resize:
[image]