# How to map QChart coordinate to QChartView point?

Tags: python, pyqt, qchart, qchartview

I want to make a rubber band window in QChart, but I don't know how to map a coordinate of QChart to QChartView.

e.g.
(0, 0) is a QChart coordinate, maybe it in QChartView is (10, 10), how to transform it?
I have saw the answer of [Get mouse coordinates in QChartView's axis system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067831/get-mouse-coordinates-in-qchartviews-axis-system/44078533#44078533)

But it seems like that it is reversed with my requirement.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, QEvent, QPoint, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QRubberBand

class ChartView(QChartView):
    def init_rubber_band(self):
        chart = self.chart()

        start1 = chart.mapToPosition(QPointF(0, 0))
        start2 = chart.mapToScene(start1)
        start3 = QPoint()
        start3.setX(int(start2.x()))
        start3.setY(int(start2.y()))

        end = QPoint(200, 200)

        self.rubber = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self);
        self.rubber.setGeometry(QRect(start3, end))
        self.rubber.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
series0 = QLineSeries()
series1 = QLineSeries()

series0 << QPointF(1, 15) << QPointF(3, 17) << QPointF(7, 16) << QPointF(9, 17) \
        << QPointF(12, 16) << QPointF(16, 17) << QPointF(18, 15)
series1 << QPointF(1, 3) << QPointF(3, 4) << QPointF(7, 3) << QPointF(8, 2) \
        << QPointF(12, 3) << QPointF(16, 4) << QPointF(18, 3)

chart = QChart()
chart.addSeries(series0)
chart.addSeries(series1)
chart.createDefaultAxes()
chartView = ChartView(chart)

chartView.init_rubber_band()

window = QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(chartView)
window.resize(400, 300)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I use `mapToPosition` to get coordinate of original point, but it seems like that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform some calculation you must do it after the widget is displayed and since `QChartView` just recalculates the items, in the following example I will create a `QRubberBand` that is on a rectangle with coordinates regarding `QChart` from `QPointF(1, 17)` to `QPointF(18, 2)`

```
class ChartView(QChartView):
    def init_rubber_band(self):
        chart = self.chart()
        start_value = QPointF(1, 17)
        end_value = QPointF(18, 2)
        start = chart.mapToPosition(start_value)
        end = chart.mapToPosition(end_value)

        self.rubber = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.rubber.setGeometry(QRect(start.toPoint(), end.toPoint()))
        self.rubber.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
series0 = QLineSeries()
series1 = QLineSeries()

series0 << QPointF(1, 15) << QPointF(3, 17) << QPointF(7, 16) << QPointF(9, 17) \
        << QPointF(12, 16) << QPointF(16, 17) << QPointF(18, 15)
series1 << QPointF(1, 3) << QPointF(3, 4) << QPointF(7, 3) << QPointF(8, 2) \
        << QPointF(12, 3) << QPointF(16, 4) << QPointF(18, 3)

chart = QChart()
chart.addSeries(series0)
chart.addSeries(series1)
chart.createDefaultAxes()
chartView = ChartView(chart)

window = QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(chartView)
window.resize(400, 300)
window.show()

chartView.init_rubber_band()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. And the rubber band rectangle should start from top left corner to lower right, I made a reversed understanding.

Comment: And I want to give you a cup of coffee, do you have Alipay?